# How to find if array exist - KnockOut

Tags: arrays, if-statement, knockout.js

I need to run the below code only if  documentation.files exist. Else it should not execute.

Something like: `<!-- if (condition-here) -- >`

```
<!-- ko foreach: documentation.files --> 
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            <a data-bind="attr: { href: file_link[$root.locale.selected_locale()]}" target="_blank">
                                            <div class="block" data-bind="html: file_name[$root.locale.selected_locale()]"></div>
                                            </a>
                                        </th>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Any help will be thankful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick if it's not initialised:

```
<!-- ko if: documentation.files -- >
```

So it will proceed if it's not `undefined`.

Or if it's setup as an empty array:

```
<!-- ko if: documentation.files.length > 0 -- >
```

I'm guessing it's the first case you would need, otherwise your `foreach` would work without this check.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it into div

```
<div data-bind="if: documentation.files">
   ...
</div>
```

or

```
<!-- ko if: documentation.files -->
   ...
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is a case of your web browser being helpful to you and causing problems.  in this example

```
<!-- ko foreach: documentation.files --> 
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        <a data-bind="attr: { href: file_link[$root.locale.selected_locale()]}" target="_blank">
                                        <div class="block" data-bind="html: file_name[$root.locale.selected_locale()]"></div>
                                        </a>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

it appears you are trying to do this binding inside a table.  If this is the case them most likely the comment blocks are being removed from the table and placed infront of it.  Causing something like this to actually appear

```
<!-- ko foreach: documentation.files --> <!-- /ko -->
                             <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        <a data-bind="attr: { href: file_link[$root.locale.selected_locale()]}" target="_blank">
                                        <div class="block" data-bind="html: file_name[$root.locale.selected_locale()]"></div>
                                        </a>
                                    </th>
                                </table>
```

now the problem with this is obvious, the solution is to use a thead tag and do your foreach in that section

```
<thead data-bind="foreach: documentation.files"> 
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        <a data-bind="attr: { href: file_link[$root.locale.selected_locale()]}" target="_blank">
                                        <div class="block" data-bind="html: file_name[$root.locale.selected_locale()]"></div>
                                        </a>
                                    </th>
                                  </tr>
</thead>
```

or if you are working in the table body use  instead.   Also if that is a direct copy you need to close your table row tag